# jquery Multiselect Rebind Issue

Tags: jquery

I am binding Multiselect jquery through code behind

and on buttton click i am rebinding with different values

it shows the changed list,

I have to disabled some items in second list if it is available in first list

suppose 
Old list1 is

Date

Revenue

New list1 is

productName

new second list is

Date

Product Family

so as Date was in oldlist1
its disabling in list2

but date is not in newlist1 so it should not disabled in list2

when i look in firebug i saw the date is avaibale in List1 like this

[image]

its keep storing old list, but its not visible in list on GUI

The code is like this

I have modified this line in jquery plugin

```
if (isDisabled || IsToDisableIfselectedInOthers(value) == true) {
                    html += ' disabled="disabled"';
                    html += ' aria-disabled="true"';
                }
```

details of IsToDisableIfselectedInOthers is

```
function IsToDisableIfselectedInOthers(val) {

             if (val.indexOf("XYA") != -1) {

                var val1 = val.replace("ltrXYAxis", "ltrXaxis");

                if ($('#lsltrXaxis , :input[value="' + val1 + '"]').filter(':checked').length > 0) {
                          return true;
                }
            }
}
```

What I am doing wrong

Why jquery keeps old values

Please Help

Thank You